# Sorting 4D numpy array but keeping one axis tied together

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

First, I looked into the question [NumPy: sorting 3D array but keeping 2nd dimension assigned to first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180777/numpy-sorting-3d-array-but-keeping-2nd-dimension-assigned-to-first) but the accepted answer doesn't quite fit to my problem as I need the full range of values possible in *uint16* and don't wish to go to *int32* to avoid using too much memory.

My problem is that I have a stack of 3D arrays (which are images with two bands each) that I want to sort along the axis of the stack (by the value of the first band) but by preserving together the two bands of each image... I hope this is somewhat clear.

Code to produce an array similar to what I have:

```
import numpy as np 
# Here a stack of three 3x2 images containing two bands each
arr = np.zeros((3,3,2,2), 'uint16')

np.random.seed(5)
arr[0,:,:,0] = np.random.randint(10, 90, 6).reshape(3,2)
arr[0,:,:,1] = 51
arr[1,:,:,0] = np.random.randint(10, 90, 6).reshape(3,2)
arr[1,:,:,1] = 52
arr[2,:,:,0] = np.random.randint(10, 90, 6).reshape(3,2)
arr[2,:,:,1] = 50
arr[np.where(arr >= 85)] = 99 #just to have couple identical values like my dataset has

>>> arr
array([[[[99, 51],
         [71, 51]],

        [[26, 51],
         [83, 51]],

        [[18, 51],
         [72, 51]]],


       [[[37, 52],
         [40, 52]],

        [[17, 52],
         [99, 52]],

        [[25, 52],
         [63, 52]]],


       [[[37, 50],
         [54, 50]],

        [[99, 50],
         [99, 50]],

        [[75, 50],
         [57, 50]]]], dtype=uint16)
```

As I wish to sort through the stack I used `arr_sorted = np.sort(arr, axis=0)` but this breaks the link between the two bands of each raster:

```
>>> arr[0,2,1,:]
array([72, 51], dtype=uint16)

>>> arr_sorted[2,2,1,:]
array([72, 52], dtype=uint16) #value 72 is no longer tied to 51 but to 52
```

I can use `idx = np.argsort(arr[:,:,:,0], axis=0)` to get the sorting index I want but I didn't find how to use `idx` to sort the same way both `arr[:,:,:,0]` and `arr[:,:,:,1]`... that's probably easy right?!

Utimately, I want to be able to sort an array of 50 x 11000 x 11000 x 2 in *uint16* so it needs to be as memory efficient as possible.

Comment: It's possible to construct a set of indices that broadcast with `idx` to do this sort, but it's a bit messy.  A recent `numpy` version as added a `np.take_along_axis` function that takes care of the details.  Try it with `idx[...,None]` to get the number of dimensions right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new `take_along_axis`:

```
In [351]: arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,3,2,2))
In [352]: idx = np.argsort(arr[...,0], axis=0)
In [353]: idx.shape
Out[353]: (3, 3, 2)
In [354]: arr1 = np.take_along_axis(arr, idx[...,None], axis=0)
```