# Reorganizing a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've tried and searched for a few days, I've come closer but need your help.

I have a 3d array in python,

```
shape(files)
>> (31,2049,2)
```

which corresponds to 31 input files with 2 columns of data with 2048 rows and a header.

I'd like to sort this array based on the header, which is a number, in each file.

I tried to follow [NumPy: sorting 3D array but keeping 2nd dimension assigned to first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180777/numpy-sorting-3d-array-but-keeping-2nd-dimension-assigned-to-first) , but i'm incredibly confused.

First I try to setup get my headers for the argsort, I thought I could do

```
sortval=files[:][0][0]
```

but this does not work..

Then I simply did a for loop to iterate and get my headers

```
for i in xrange(shape(files)[0]:
    sortval.append([i][0][0])
```

Then

```
sortedIdx = np.argsort(sortval)
```

This works, however I dont understand whats happening in the last line..

```
files = files[np.arange(len(deck))[:,np.newaxis],sortedIdx]
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use a simple example to demonstrate what your code is doing:

First we create a random 3D numpy matrix:

```
a = (np.random.rand(3,3,2)*10).astype(int)
array([[[3, 1],
        [3, 7],
        [0, 3]],
       [[2, 9],
        [1, 0],
        [9, 2]],
       [[9, 2],
        [8, 8],
        [8, 0]]])
```

Then `a[:]` will gives `a` itself, and `a[:][0][0]` is just the first row in first 2D array in `a`, which is:

```
a[:][0]
# array([[3, 1],
#        [3, 7],
#        [0, 3]])

a[:][0][0]
# array([3, 1])
```

What you want is the header which are `3,2,9` in this example, so we can use `a[:, 0, 0]` to extract them:

```
a[:,0,0]
# array([3, 2, 9])
```

Now we sort the above list and get an index array:

```
np.argsort(a[:,0,0])
# array([1, 0, 2])
```

In order to rearrange the entire 3D array, we need to slice the array with correct order. And `np.arange(len(a))[:,np.newaxis]` is equal to `np.arange(len(a)).reshape(-1,1)` which creates a sequential 2D index array:

```
np.arange(len(a))[:,np.newaxis]
# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2]])
```

Without the 2D array, we will slice the array to 2 dimension

```
a[np.arange(3), np.argsort(a[:,0,0])]
# array([[3, 7],
#        [2, 9],
#        [8, 0]])
```

With the 2D array, we can perform 3D slicing and keeps the shape:

```
a[np.arange(3).reshape(-1,1), np.argsort(a[:,0,0])]
array([[[3, 7],
        [3, 1],
        [0, 3]],
       [[1, 0],
        [2, 9],
        [9, 2]],
       [[8, 8],
        [9, 2],
        [8, 0]]])
```

And above is the final result you want.

Edit:

To arange the 2D arrays:, one could use:

```
a[np.argsort(a[:,0,0])]
array([[[2, 9],
        [1, 0],
        [9, 2]],
       [[3, 1],
        [3, 7],
        [0, 3]],
       [[9, 2],
        [8, 8],
        [8, 0]]])
```

Comment: Dear Kevin, thank you for the reply.  However I do not want to change the individual sub-arrays, only rearrange them within the 3D array.  e.g. in your example, to finish with [[[2,9],,],[3,1],,],[9,2],,].  I can reword the question to clarify.

Comment: @LearningPython then `a[np.argsort(a[:,0,0])]` would do that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with `np.take`

```
header = a[:,0,0]
sorted = np.take(a, np.argsort(header), axis=0)
```